# SQL Server and Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
IF EXISTS((SELECT user_type FROM users WHERE user_id=@user_id)=2)
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET Status=2 WHERE User_id=@user_id
END
```

Comment: Yes - and ?!?!? You forgot to **ask a question** here! Please read [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Another option is simply `UPDATE users SET Status=2 WHERE User_id=@user_id AND user_type = 2` - it will update Zero rows if the user isn't `type 2`.

Comment: And the question ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT user_type FROM users WHERE user_id=@user_id and user_type=2)
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET Status=2 WHERE User_id=@user_id
END
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have done that is not feasible syntax in Sql

I think You are try to achieve this..

```
   IF ((SELECT top 1 user_type FROM users WHERE user_id=@user_id)=2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET Status=2 WHERE User_id=@user_id
    END
```

Comment: If It is your Solution Than Mark As Correct @AbdulMulla ...!!Welcome to Stackoverflow..